# Nesting api calls to populate Table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, nested, material-ui

I have a table with some nested conditions.

Basically, I have two api calls. One retrieves a list of new cars, and the other retrieves a list of customers who would be interested in that car.

I want to populate a table with two columns:

Name of Car     |   Customers who are interested in car

Mazda Miata       |   Mary Jane and 1 other

Honda Civic       |    Billy Joel and 5 others

So the first api call /inventory/:idOfDealership/cars returns

```js
[
{name: "Mazda Miata", idOfCar: 16},
{name: "Ford Fiesta", idOfCar: 18},
{name: "Honda Civic", idOfCar: 90}
]
```

and the second api call would be made based on the results of the first, I would grab the id of the car and insert it into the second api call /customers/:idOfCar/interestedCustomers 
which would return

```js
 [
      {name: "MacInteyer Williams", id: 1},
      {name: "Deborah Fierce", id: 2},
       {name: "Mary Jane", id:3 }
     ]
```

The tricky thing is that I am populating a table based on these values. I have the table working for the first API call. But I am wondering how I can populate the second column with the customers to notify, something like "Mary Jane and 2 others"

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn
} from 'material-ui/Table';

export default class PolicyTable extends React.Component {
  state = { TableData: [], data: [] };
  getInitialState() {
    return { data: [], TableData: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialConditions = [];
    let self = this;
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/inventory/:idOfDealership/cars')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        self.setState({ TableData: data });
      });

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/customers/16/customersToNotify')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        self.setState({ customersToNotify: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Table>
            <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false}>
              <TableRow>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Customers To Contact</TableHeaderColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
              {this.state.TableData.map((TableData, i) => (
                <TableRow key={i} value={name}>
                  <TableRowColumn />
                  <TableRowColumn>{TableData.name}</TableRowColumn>
                  <TableRowColumn />
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So far I think I would have to call the fetch on every .map iteration, by grabbing the id from the first api call, inserting it into the second api call, and then putting the results in that cell.

Please can someone verify my thinking on this? It's an interesting problem, I want to make sure I'm going about it the right way.

Comment: Do you have control of the server? You could maybe create your own endpoint to reduce the amount of calls you have to make. If not, then what you described seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @WilliamChou unfortunately not in this case.

Comment: why not just create a new object that merges two object in relation to the id. i would think of it like this ```{ name: 'car', interested: [{ name: 'person1', id: 1 }, { name: 'person2', id: 1 }], id: 1 }```

Comment: @ReiDien I could do that. I'm in a crunch so leaning towards the other method. Do you have an example of how to merge them like that?